# Whole site's pagination not working after rewriting product permalink

Tags: permalinks, pagination

I have to rewrite the product's permalink by changing it from the default **/product/product-name** into **/%product-cat%/product-name**. **%product-cat%** is a custom category. But after I rewrite it, the pagination for product review is not working. Not matter what page I click, the url is correct but the reviews are always stuck at first page. This is my first attempt on doing a permalink rewrite. Did I missed out anything or added wrong line of code thus causing the pagination query to fail?

Below is the rewrite code that I have attempt:

```
function product_perma_Rewrite() {

    $prodCat = ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'];
    $categories = get_categories($prodCat);
    $catSlug = [];
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $catSlug[] = $category->slug;
    }
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^('.implode('|', $catSlug).')/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?post_type=product&category=$matches[1]&product=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'product_perma_Rewrite');
```

Comment: There is no pagination rule, how will WP pick up that it's page 2 or pass `2` etc into the query string? Take a look at the post and page rewrite rules, they have checks on the end for pagination and query variables that your rule doesn't have. Also, flushing rewrite rules on `init` can be extremely expensive and cause bugs. It should be enough just to visit the permalinks settings page without saving to flush rules

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it fixed with the advice from tom. This is the solution I tried.

```
function product_perma_Rewrite() {

    $prodCat = ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'];
    $categories = get_categories($prodCat);
    $catSlug = [];
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $catSlug[] = $category->slug;
    }
    
     add_rewrite_rule(
        '^('.implode('|', $catSlug).')/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=product&category=$matches[1]&product=$matches[2]&cpage=$matches[3]','top'
    );
    
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^('.implode('|', $catSlug).')/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?post_type=product&category=$matches[1]&product=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'product_perma_Rewrite');
```